# Creating MSSQL Database from .sql, .bcp files

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I don't have any clue how to deal with this. I have bunch of *.sql table files and some table .bcp files, 3 commit .bat files. 
Actually I need the relationship diagrams and attributes in those tables. I don't need any data from it. Just require the Table Attributes / Schema of the tables. Total size of folder is 3.3GB. I am using Win8.
How can I create a database from these files in MS SQLExpress Server? Screenshot of some files are here.
[image: SCREENSHOT OF LIST OF FILES]

[COMMIT_SD.BAT FILE HAS](http://codepad.org/o20Z4iye)

[COMMIT_SL.BAT FILE HAS](http://codepad.org/51QPE661)

[COMMIT_SDL.BAT FILE HAS](http://codepad.org/JEQCAl1f)

Comment: Read what the batch file is doing and post that

Comment: Links Updated :p COD4

Comment: I have the backup of DB from WIN2000 Server with SQL Server 2000. It has *.bak extension. I tried to restore it on Win2003 Server with SQL Server 2000 but its giving me error. No I got a tool to recover the tables from *.bak file. Which are these files. From which I currently am trying to make a DB and restore in SQLExpress. Clear

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the error: http://i.imgur.com/HCZgkxH.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32458/discussion-between-yopakistan-com-and-devart)

Comment: No problem buddy, take your time. I tried without forcing, gives the same error.